# Cypress not matching routes

Tags: testing, mocking, cypress

I am trying to write a cypress test that emulates a slow API, so after reading some documentation I came up with this:

```
before(function() {
    cy.server({delay: 5000});
});

beforeEach(() => {
    cy.route({
        method: "GET",
        url: "**/api/**"
    });
    cy.visit("http://localhost:9000");
});
```

That should add a 5 second delay to all requests to `API`, right?

The issue I am seeing is that it is not matching to any requests even through there are plenty of calls to `*/api/*`.
The cypress GUI does however see the route... it is just not matching.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: When you run the test you should see in the GUI the actual route, what I normally do is copy that route as the matcher and it works.

Comment: @munHunger Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

If you put in the entire route, as it appears in the cypress log, you will probably find that it works.

It seems like the look-ahead globbing isn't implemented very well by minimatch.  It delimits fine on the `/` char but not so well on `?` or `#`, so if you're trying to accommodate query strings, this is probably where you're coming unstuck.

You can use `Cypress.minimatch` in the console to see what's going on. More info on how to do this [in the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/minimatch.html#Usage).

Cypress will also accept regexes. Something like `/\/api\//` should work for you.

Comment: I agree with you that it should work, but some reason it doesn't. I've tried both with regex and adding an absolute URL, but nothing works

Comment: Can you provide an example of the kind of URL you are trying to match?

Answer (score 3):

For me, my pattern was correct for my POST request but the issue was I wasn't overriding the default response. I was just hoping the API would return a 500 error, but unless I specified a response, it called through to the real API endpoint. The documentation says the default response is an empty object, but for some reason it's calling through unless I provide a value. Once I provided the response, the Cypress GUI displayed that it was properly stubbing out the call.

Changing this from:

```
cy.route({
    method: "POST",
    url: /my-endpoint/,
    status: 500,
});
```

to

```
cy.route({
    method: "POST",
    url: /my-endpoint/,
    response: {},
    status: 500,
});
```

is what worked for me.

Comment: Nice find Greg. I came to a similar conclusion oddly enough but I'm trying to work out how I can return an empty body content as return just an empty string seems to have the same behavior as not specifying a response as well. Seems like there must be a falsy check somewhere.

Comment: This documentation page states this behavior directly.

"If you do not pass a response to a route, Cypress will pass the request through without stubbing it. We can still wait for the request to resolve later."

https://docs.w3cub.com/cypress/api/commands/route.html

Comment: It appears that the issue I described with falsy values still causing the route to be ignored had been addressed in v4.11.0 for anybody else who may be running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your matcher is not working and your request does not say (XHR STUB)

If you are using the GUI, you should see a request that will look like this

(XHR) GET 200 /YOUR_API/YOUR_ROUTE

copy that (/YOUR_API/YOUR_ROUTE) and it should match

if should say (XHR STUB) after you stub it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you making a direct XHR request, or are you using `fetch`? Cypress network stubbing/mocking **only** works with actual XHR requests (fetch is its own type of request).

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/95) (3+ years old) about this, and buried in there is a great link to some [solutions](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/stubbing-spying__window-fetch), including this one below, which works brilliantly.

EDIT: Alternatively, you could use axios for your HTTP requests, which sends actual XHR requests instead of fetch requests, so no Cypress config is needed. I think the resulting code is cleaner as well.

```js
  let polyfill;

  // grab fetch polyfill from remote URL, could be also from a local package
  before(() => {
    const polyfillUrl = 'https://unpkg.com/unfetch/dist/unfetch.umd.js'
    cy.request(polyfillUrl)
      .then((response) => {
        polyfill = response.body
      })
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/', {
      onBeforeLoad (win) {
        delete win.fetch
        // since the application code does not ship with a polyfill
        // load a polyfilled "fetch" from the test
        win.eval(polyfill)
        win.fetch = win.unfetch
      },
    })
  });
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. For those of us who don't know that Cypress doesn't mock native fetch (only XHR), this little helper is a god send!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Maccurt's solution and after reading [Glob-Pattern-Matching-URLs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Glob-Pattern-Matching-URLs) , I would suggest you use the [Digital Ocean's Glob Tool](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2F%2A%2A%2F%2A.js&matches=false&tests=%2F%2F%20This%20will%20match%20as%20it%20ends%20with%20%27.js%27&tests=%2Fhello%2Fworld.js&tests=%2F%2F%20This%20won%27t%20match%21&tests=%2Ftest%2Fsome%2Fglobs) to test your URL. Once you're confident that the glob-pattern works exactly as you expected, simply copy it like this:

[image: Glob Pattern Match Sample]

```
// Matches the URL with HTTP methods(POST, GET, PUT, PATCH & DELETE) and invokes the response to be empty
cy.intercept({ url: '**/user/create-user/*' }, [])
```

[image: Cypress Result]

**P.S** : cy.route no longer exists!